# How do I set my default theme for all icons on Antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am looking to set the default theme for all the Icons that I'm using through ANTD to 'filled' rather than having to pass theme='filled' to every individual icon I create. I have many instances of Icon throughout my APP and going to pass in that to every one (as well as modals) , it would be time consuming. How can I go about setting a default theme on all icons to be 'filled' without changing every instance (also effecting icons used in modals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to modify at one place and it will reflect to all places. But you can always wrap Icon component of andt for your custom component like following

```
const CustomIcon = (props) => {
     return (
         <Icon theme="filled" {...props} />
     )
}
```

Also, you can use regex to search the icon component in all your files and change/add theme to filled.

**NOTE: Many icons in default theme are not present in other themes.**

Comment: Thank you fore the suggestion! I appreciate it!